# Detect whether a row exists with a SQL IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to check in SQL whether a given value exists in one of my tables inside a stored procedure. This is the method I used:

```
IF( (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM my_Table WHERE [Col] = @SP_Parameter) > 0)
BEGIN
   --My Code
END
```

But that statement is never true no matter what. I made sure the row exists, but it never runs as true.

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: SQL (the query language) has no `IF` statement

Comment: What is the type of @SP_Parameter and what is the collation of Database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it does.

Comment: No. SQL the query language does not have an `IF` statement. Microsoft's SQL Server uses T-SQL which does indeed have `IF` statement - but that is not part of "SQL" (the standardized query language)

Answer (score 4):

If your code doesn't work, then nothing matches the `WHERE` clause.  Or, you are misinterpreting the results.

This answer will not fix that problem.  But the better way to write the condition is:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_Table WHERE [Col] = @SP_Parameter) )
BEGIN
   --My Code
END;
```

This is less expensive than doing an aggregation query because it can stop at the first matching row.

Comment: But on the other hand they use `COUNT([ID])` thus ignoring `NULL`s in `[ID]` (unless that column is declared `NUT NULL`, which doesn't seem unlikely but we don't know). So it might be necessary to extend the `WHERE` clause with a `AND [ID] IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: It also works for the: 
IIF(Exists(select 1 from my_table where col = @SP_parameter),true,false)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 
If somebody is looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS () in SQL.
 try this query

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT top 1 [ID] FROM my_Table WHERE [Col] = @SP_Parameter )
BEGIN
   --My Code
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EmployeeAllowedStatuses WHERE EmployeeAllowedStatuses_ID=EmployeeAllowedStatuses_ID)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'RECORD ALREADY EXISTS' as Result
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'RECORD NOT EXISTS' as Result
END


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM dbo.EmployeeAllowedStatuses WHERE EmployeeAllowedStatuses_ID=EmployeeAllowedStatuses_ID)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'RECORD NOT EXISTS' as Result
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'RECORD ALREADY EXISTS' as Result

END
```